# which delimiter can I use safely to separate zlib deflated strings in node

Tags: node.js, zlib, deflate

I need to send content from a client to a remote server using node.js.
The content can be anything (a user can upload any file).

Each piece of content is compressed by `zlib.deflate` before sending it to the remote.
I prefer not to make multiple roundtrips and send the entire content at once.

To separate between each piece of content, I need a character that can't be used in the compressed string, so I can split it safely on the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such character or sequence of characters. zlib compressed data can contain *any* sequence of bytes.

You could encode the zlib compressed data to avoid one byte value, expanding compressed data slightly. Then you could use that one byte value as a delimiter.

Example code:

```
// Example of encoding binary data to a sequence of bytes with no zero values.
// The result is expanded slightly. On average, assuming random input, the
// expansion is less than 0.1%. The maximum expansion is less than 14.3%, which
// is reached only if the input is a sequence of bytes all with value 255.

#include <stdio.h>

// Encode binary data read from in, to a sequence of byte values in 1..255
// written to out. There will be no zero byte values in the output. The
// encoding is decoding a flat (equiprobable) Huffman code of 255 symbols.
void no_zeros_encode(FILE *in, FILE *out) {
    unsigned buf = 0;
    int bits = 0, ch;
    do {
        if (bits < 8) {
            ch = getc(in);
            if (ch != EOF) {
                buf += (unsigned)ch << bits;
                bits += 8;
            }
            else if (bits == 0)
                break;
        }
        if ((buf & 127) == 127) {
            putc(255, out);
            buf >>= 7;
            bits -= 7;
        }
        else {
            unsigned val = buf & 255;
            buf >>= 8;
            bits -= 8;
            if (val < 127)
                val++;
            putc(val, out);
        }
    } while (ch != EOF);
}

// Decode a sequence of byte values made by no_zeros_encode() read from in, to
// the original binary data written to out. The decoding is encoding a flat
// Huffman code of 255 symbols. no_zeros_encode() will not generate any zero
// byte values in its output (that's the whole point), but if there are any
// zeros in the input to no_zeros_decode(), they are ignored.
void no_zeros_decode(FILE *in, FILE *out) {
    unsigned buf = 0;
    int bits = 0, ch;
    while ((ch = getc(in)) != EOF)
        if (ch != 0) {              // could flag any zeros as an error
            if (ch == 255) {
                buf += 127 << bits;
                bits += 7;
            }
            else {
                if (ch <= 127)
                    ch--;
                buf += (unsigned)ch << bits;
                bits += 8;
            }
            if (bits >= 8) {
                putc(buf, out);
                buf >>= 8;
                bits -= 8;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. About your suggestion, I'm not sure I fully understand it. Is it about doing something like `zlib.deflateSync(myContent).toString('base64')` so then the content is encoded to base64 and then I could use any character that is invalid in base64? If so, I guess it could work but then the data gets bigger.

Comment: Like that, but not that. Base 64 results in a 35% expansion. You can get rid of one byte value with 0.1% expansion.

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of one byte value", can you please elaborate on how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: To encode, _decode_ a flat (equal probability) Huffman code of 255 symbols. Use the bytes values 1..255 for the symbols. Then the zero byte will not appear. To decode, _encode_ the flat Huffman code of 255 symbols.